# How to make font appear on all devices?

Tags: html, css, fonts, responsive

I'm using the google font "spectral" on my website: magpieandcapricorn.com
I've just started learning about responsive design and got it somewhat working. However, I noticed the Spectral font shows up on my Iphone but not my husbands Android? What can I do to fix this? Is there a code to change the default text to a substitute font for devices that can't use Spectral?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24912157) your question with how you are configuring the font as well as testing. it may help to know the model name and OS version of all Android devices you are using to check.

Answer (score 1):

**Embed Font**

To embed your selected fonts into a webpage, copy the following code into the `<head>` of your HTML document:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

**Specify in CSS**

Use the following CSS rules to specify these families:

```
font-family: 'Spectral', serif;
```

For examples of how fonts can be added to webpages, see the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).